# Clojure reduce overflows when in function, but not when passed directly into REPL

Tags: clojure, reduce

I am having great trouble debugging an overflow that apparently happens only when I am using the statement in a function.

This is the function I have:

```
(defn sum-records
    [senset votemap]
    (let [voteset (select-keys votemap senset)]
        (reduce (fn [v1 v2] (mapv + v1 v1)) (vals voteset))))
```

The problem seems to be coming from the line with `reduce`. However, when I run that line on its own in the repl on the data, it works perfectly fine. I have checked to make sure that the data I am testing with at repl is indeed the same as what becomes `voteset` in the function. I have even inserted `println` statements within the function to verify this.

I'm really stuck here, and would greatly appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an integer overflow:

```
 (reduce (fn [v1 v2] (mapv + v1 v1)) (repeat 1000 (range 10)))
 => ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1501)
```

You must ensure the input data to be something else, or cast to bigint in the `+` function, or use [+'](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/+') as pointed out by @ClojureMostly that supports arbitrary precision.

All this approaches work:

```
  (reduce (fn [v1 v2] (mapv +' v1 v1)) (repeat 1000 (range 0 10)))
   => [0N 535754303593133660474212524...

  (reduce (fn [v1 v2] (mapv + v1 v1)) (repeat 1000 (range 0N 10N)))
   => [0N 535754303593133660474212524...

  (reduce (fn [v1 v2] (mapv + v1 v1)) (repeat 1000 (map bigint (range 10))))
   => [0N 5357543035931336604742125245300009052...

  (reduce (fn [v1 v2] (mapv #(+ (bigint %1) (bigint %2)) v1 v1)) (repeat 1000 (range 10)))
   => [0N 53575430359313366...
```

Comment: Why not use `+'`?

Comment: Didn't know about that, I'll update the answer, thank you

Comment: Oh no I realized my bug was sitting in plain sight! What I wanted to do with my reduce is to add `v1` and `v2` together! I never had an overfflow when I was testing my line separately, because my data size is not too large, so I coouldn't understand why it would lead to overflow in a function! Thank you so much for your help though! When I saw the repeated `v1` in your `mapv` lines, it promtped me to re-check my source!